# Define keybindings for R in Visual Studio Code

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code to write and edit my R-scripts. Therefore I want to create some keybindings like:

`nrow(*selected*)`

`length(*selected*)`

So i installed the 'R Extension Pack' (with R & R LSP Client) for Visual Studio. With "ctrl + enter" i could run selected code like this:

```
{ "key": "ctrl+enter",
  "command": "r.runSelection",                               
  "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == 'r'" }
```

But how could I run the selection to get the nrow() or length()?

Comment: Unrelated, but you might want to consider the [R Tools extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Mikhail-Arkhipov.r) which will define keybindings like Ctrl+Enter, Ctrl+Shift+S, etc.

Comment: R Tools don`t run on my VS Code. I can`t define my R Version. Nevertheless, thanks for this post Hong Ooi.

Answer (score 0):

`nrow(*selected*)`: Ctrl-1

`length(*selected*)`: Ctrl-2

You can’t define custom functions like this but there’s an open issue for it: https://github.com/Ikuyadeu/vscode-R/issues/201